# Iterate through specific control and assigning a property to it

Tags: c#, asp.net, for-loop, checkbox

Suppose I have three check boxes named `chk1`, `chk2`, and `chk3` in ASP.NET. Is is possible to assign a property to each of them programmatically by appending the number to the variable name and using a `for` loop?

For example:

```
for (int x=1; x<=3; x++)
{
   chk+[x].Checked = true;
}
```

If this is not possible, can you give me a better solution or approach to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Presuming winforms(ASP.NET tag was added later), you can use [`ControlCollection.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx), the second parameter specifies if all child controls should also be searched:

```
for (int x=1; x<=3; x++)
{
    Control[] ctrl = this.Controls.Find("chk" + x, true);
    foreach (CheckBox chk in ctrl.OfType<CheckBox>())
        chk.Checked = true;
}
```

If it's actually ASP.NET you could use this recursive search extension-method:

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Control> GetControlsRecursively(this Control parent)
    {
        foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
        {
            yield return c;

            if (c.HasControls())
            {
                foreach (Control control in c.GetControlsRecursively())
                {
                    yield return control;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you get all checkboxes with these ID's in this way:

```
var allIDs = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(i => "chk" + i).ToList();
var allCheckBoxes = this.GetControlsRecursively().OfType<CheckBox>()
    .Where(chk => allIDs.Contains(chk.ID));
foreach(CheckBox chk in allCheckBoxes)
    chk.Checked = true;
```

However, i would rarely use this recursive method. It's a little bit error-prone since other NamingContainers can contain the same ID again. Instead i would only use the right `NamingContainer`. For example, if you have a `Panel` where all releated CheckBoxes are sitting you can simply use `myPanel.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()`.

Also, you should use more meaningful ID's for your controls. Then you cannot use such loops anymore but you can start to write more robust and maintainable code like:

```
chkUserActive.Checked = true;  // just an example
```

Comment: @SageTheGreat: i've added an ASP.NET approach

Comment: @SageTheGreat: i've added some notes.